# Unable to access localhost

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run Jupyter notebook on Chrome (I'm using Windows 10), when I try to access it (localhost:8888) I keep on getting the message that it can't be reached.

I have looked it up and some say that I need to use a proxy to ignore localhost:8888, I tried but I don't think I'm doing it the right way.

I tried adding an inbound rule to allow port 8888 but it didn't work.

This is what I keep getting on Chrome:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The web page at http://localhost:8888/
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address.
>
> ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

Comment: What is the result of using `127.0.0.1:8888`?

Comment: Or just `localhost` on the default port?

Comment: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1:8888` both give the same message as the one mentioned above. @Anaksunaman @Mawg